# Is expectation over some of the variables same as conditional expectation over the other variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Probably a silly question, but I don't see measure-theoretic probability books have mentioned this. In many applied fields (like computer science), I see very often that people take expectation over only a subset of variables, e.g., 
$$E_{X}[f(X,Y)]$$

This is the expectation over only $X$. Is it essentially the same as
$$E[f(X,Y)|Y]?$$

Comment: The notation $E_X(f(X,Y))$ is awful, to tell the truth. One interpretation could be that $E_X(f(X,Y))=g(Y)$ where, for every $y$, $g(y)=E(f(X,y))$. Dunno...

Comment: @Did So just as what I wrote (conditional on $Y$)?

Comment: No, except when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @Did Why? What you wrote ($g(Y)$) seems the same as $E[f(X,Y)|Y]$

Comment: No, for example if $f(x,y)=xy$ and $X=Y$, then $E(f(X,Y)\mid Y)=Y^2$ while $g(Y)=E(Y)Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the two terms are the same [cf. Kallenberg].

Comment: I am considering the general situation where X,Y are not necessarily independent. I just want to know what is the measure theoretic interpretation of the $E_{X}[f(X,Y)]$,

Comment: Then it is a matter of notation. Usually $E_X$ means you only integrate over $X$, but this doesn't work if your random variables aren't independent.

Comment: OK. This kind of notation appears very often in the computer science literature. Probably just not that rigorous.